# Finding probability mass function of this particular case

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I'm completely clueless when it comes to computing the probability mass function of something. Could anyone walk me through an example problem or anything to give me any guidance (Not necessarily the above problem)? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a discrete random variable $X$, then a probability mass function $F$ is defined  as $F_{X}(y) = P[X = y]$, for any $y \in (-\infty, \infty)$. Here your disrete random variable $X$ is defined as $X = \text{\{number of complete, distinct pairs of mittens that you have left\}}$. So, here, to find the probability mass function, you have to find $P[X = i]$ for any natural $i > 0$. Note, that the kittens will hide excatly $4$ mittens, so in the best case, there will be $6$ pairs remaning (the kittens will take two pairs of mittens), in the worst case, $4$ pairs(they will take left or right mitten from $4$ distinct types). So. for any $x \notin \{4, 5, 6\} \; P[X = x] = 0$.

Now, Let's find, for example, $P[X = 6]$:

Note, that there are $\binom{16}{4}$ possible diffrent combinations of pairs that the kittens can take. 
If you have $6$ distinct pairs left, than the kittens have taken two comlete pairs. The number of possible combination for this is $\binom{8}{2}$ (we choose the $2$ pairs out of $8$ possible that the kittens will take), so $P[X = 6] = \frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{16}{4}}$.
Similarily, you can find $P[X = 4]$ and $P[X = 5]$.

Comment: If you add them together, you will get $1$. You should just find $P[X = 4]$, and then $P[X = 5] = 1 - P[X = 4] - P[X = 6]$. Note that your task is just to compute $P[X = y]$ for any $y$, so this is enough.You can also read more about probability mass functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function)

Comment: Note that $X = 4$ means that the kittens have taken a mitten from $4$ diffrent parts. So, first, as you noted, the number of all possible combinations of $4$ pairs is $\binom{8}{4}$. But note, that in each pair, the kittens could have taken the left or the right mitten, so the number of all combinations that you need is $2^{4} \cdot \binom{8}{4}$, not $\binom{8}{4}$. Also, you don't have to find $P[X = 5]$, just substract. And if you're not sure in such problems, you can solve a similar problem with $4$ pairs, for exapmle, and just manually write down all combinations to check your formula.

Comment: Thank you. That makes so much more sense now with your explanation!

Comment: Because when $X = 6$, the kittens will take two complete pairs, so no matter what element in the pair you will choose, you'll have to take the other one as well.

Comment: $E[X] = 4 \cdot P[X = 4] + 5 \cdot P[X = 5] + 6 \cdot P[X = 6]$ Also, please try to solve your tasks yourself, or read some lectures on probability if you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'll outline one possible approach. We need to find $\Pr(X = i)$ for $i = 4,5,6$. Note that we only have to choose two values of $i$ to compute, then we can subtract from $1$ to get the last one.

We could choose to calculate $\Pr(X = 4)$ first. What is the situation in which exactly four pairs are left? Well, the kittens would have had to steal a mitten from four *different* pairs. See if you can calculate this probability.

Another easy one is $\Pr(X = 6)$. There are six pairs left if the kittens stole mittens from only two pairs.

After this, we find that $\Pr(X = 5) = 1 - \Pr(X = 4) - \Pr(X = 6)$.